# Getting UIMA working with Eclipse-- Cannot find main for Document Analyzer

Tags: uima

I am trying to set up UIMA for Java with Eclipse.

I downloaded the UIMA binary zip from Apache, unzipped it, put it in a directory that I configured as 
the UIMA_HOME environment variable in my bash profile and in eclipse. I also set my paths as the 
UIMA readme instructs. I ran adjustExamplePaths.sh from the terminal with no errors. I am able to run 
the document analyzer through the terminal with no errors; I am able to see the example annotations.

In eclipse I downloaded the EMF plugin and both UIMA plugins. Then to test if everything works in 
Eclipse, I imported (from existing projects) the examples folder in UIMA_HOME. I run it, select 
document analyzer from the list and I get the following error:

Error: could not find or load main class org.apache.uima.tools.docanalyzer.DocumentAnalyzer

Since tehn I've added the uima-tools.jar to the class path for doc analyzer and I am still getting the 
same error.

Any advice would help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently a problem with the run configurations that ship with Eclipse. This is being investigated by the UIMA developers.

```
On 18.08.2015, at 05:38, Marshall Schor <msa@schor.com> wrote:

tracked this down to a couple of lines that have sneaked into the launch
configurations that are associated with Maven / eclipse integration.

When those lines are removed, the launchers work.
```

http://markmail.org/message/fhznbjdeiafv7ke2

Comment: Thanks. Instead of automatically importing the example files, I mainly attached the jars to the build path and was sucessful.